# How to save changes to a file using python3 ?(Replace one line of string and write it back to the same position in file)

Tags: python-3.x

First of all forgive me for my not so good English.
I am also a beginner in Python coding.(I do assembly for pic micros)
I have spent several hours searching for the right answer but could not find any that answers my problem.
So,
I have a file which contains lines like this:
(the filename is users.dat)

```
1,123235122,Name
1,044235211,Name
2,264258147,Name
etc
etc...
end
```

The numbers on the beginning of each line, are status numbers, and those are the ones I want to change, here's when:
I have built two cardreader units, and when a card is read, the reader sends a unitid(which is also 1 or 2), a "," and the card ID number that consists of 9 characters(like:264258147).(The actual received data stream for example is: b'1,264258147')
The code reads the file line by line, checks the string ,
    if cardid ==(line[2:11]):
when there is a match, the unitid number is compared to the status number on the beginning of that line.
If the sent unit id number is 1, and in the file the status number is 2, then the status needs to be changed also to 1, and saved back to the file, to the same line where it was before.Same goes if the unit id is 2 and the status is 1.(If the unit id number is not equal to status number, the status number must change to match the unit id number)It does not matter if the old line will be deleted, the code anyway makes the whole string with the changed status number. The only problem I have left with, is how to write back the changed line to the file it came from(to the same file).
I have found several explanations which save the new modified line to a new file, but that's Not what I need, and does not solve my problem.
Here is the code that reads the data from the cardreaders, checks the matching IDs, and replies back to the readers, but does not write back the changed data to the file. Tested on the built actual hardware.(I figured out(i guess..) that maybe the fileinput method is not the way to go, but then, what is the right way of doing this?)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial
import fileinput    # https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fileinput.html
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',baudrate = 9600)

while 1:   # Endless loop, wait for serial data
    incoming=ser.read(11)    # Read 11 bytes
    s= str(incoming)    #
    print(s)
    cardid=(s[4:13]) # extract card id to cardid
    unitid=int(s[2]) # extract unitid, convert it to integer
    print('Card ID=',cardid) # Print both values just to be sure
    print('Unit ID=',unitid)
#----------------------------------------------------
    for line in fileinput.input(['users.dat']): 
        if cardid ==(line[2:11]):  # compare cardid to number in current line
            user=(line[12:]) 
            status=int(line[0]) 
            print('Status:',(status))
            print('User`s name:',(user)) 
            if unitid == status :
                if unitid==1:
                    print('Already checked IN')
                    print(line)
                    ser.write(b'\xAB') #Return message to cardreader unit(already checked in or out)
                    fileinput.close()  
                    break  
                if unitid == 2:
                    print('Already checked OUT')
                    print(line)
                    ser.write(b'\xAB') # Return message to cardreader unit(already checked in or out)
                    fileinput.close()
                    break
            if unitid!= status:
                if unitid==1:
                    print('Check in succesful!')
                    print(line)
                    newline = ('1,'+ cardid + ','+ user) # THE LINE THAT SHOULD REPLACE THE OLD LINE IN users.dat
                    print(newline)
                    ser.write(b'\xAA') #Return message to cardreader unit(success)
                    fileinput.close()
                    break  
                if unitid == 2:
                    print('Check out succesful')
                    print(line)
                    newline = ('2,'+ cardid + ','+ user) # THE LINE THAT SHOULD REPLACE THE OLD LINE IN users.dat
                    print(newline)
                    ser.write(b'\xAA') # Return message to cardreader unit(success)
                    fileinput.close()
                    break
        else:         
            if (line[0:3]) =='end':
                fileinput.close()
                print('Unknown card!') 
                ser.write(b'\xAC') # Return message to cardreader unit(Card not in database)
```

So, the question is: How to write back the contents of newline to the original file(users.dat),
or just the first character from newline(the status number), since the rest of the string is unchanged.
I really hope I have explained well what I want to be able to do.
Thank You all in advance!

Comment: use a proper database

Comment: So you're _only_ changing the 1 to a 2 or vice versa? Not changing the length of any data?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Only 1 to 2 and vice versa.